# facebook graph api : subscribe someone else's page to my app

Tags: node.js, facebook

I am creating a Facebook bot using which user can chat with the Facebook page.

Following is the scenario:

1. Allow user to login with his Facebook account along with required
   permissions
2. Show user list of his pages
3. When user select on of the page; subscribe **MY FACEBOOK APP** to
   that page
4. Setup webhook for app
5. Send-Receive message to/from user's Facebook page

I am having trouble with 3rd point. I tried to subscribe app using following code as mentioned in facebook docs

```
 FB.api(
'ACCESS_TOKEN',
      '/<PAGE_ID>/subscribed_apps',
      'POST',
      {"subscribed_fields":"[\n  \"feed\"\n]"},
      function(response) {
          // Insert your code here
      }
    );
```

and it returns following response:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

The problem is- I don't know which app is subscribed for this page; I can have 100 apps. Graph api don't have provision to provide app id which need to subscribe against user page.
[This is facebook doc for subscription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/page/subscribed_apps#Creating)

Comment: _“Graph api don't have provision to provide app id”_ - doesn’t need to, that information is automatically implied via the access token you are using - says so right there in the first paragraph of the documentation section you linked to: _“The app that the access token is for is installed for the page.”_

Comment: @04FS Thanks for your quick input. Are you saying i should use my app access token instead of user's page access token as i am already mentioning page id in api request?

Comment: No, of course I am not saying that. The documentation clearly states that you need to use a page access token. That page token contains the info which app id it belongs to already.

Comment: @04FS User page is not associated with any app by default.When we create new page, it does not ask for application. We can create page without application.

Comment: The page token is associated with the app id that was used when the token was created.

Comment: @04FS Thank you so much!!!! Finally found the solution- Use same app to login user and subscribe to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get page access token for app, you need to use same app to login user and to subscriber to user's page.

This makes total sense as user is granting our app to their pages and provide us access token with the reference of our app.

Solution :

1. Allow user to login with his Facebook account along with required
   permissions and your Facebook app
2. Show user list of his pages
3. When user select on of the page; subscribe YOUR FACEBOOK APP to that
   page using page access token obtained in step 2
4. Setup webhook for app
5. Send-Receive message to/from user's Facebook page